# create a variable iterating over a column in a large dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a variable named `transition` to a `dataframe` which adds 1 to every change in the variable `V2010` of each `KeyInd`.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

| keyInd | V1016 | V2010 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110000016107-1 | 1 | 4 |
| 110000016107-1 | 2 | 4 |
| 110000016107-1 | 3 | 4 |
| 110000016107-1 | 4 | 4 |
| 110000016107-1 | 5 | 2 |
| 110000016107-2 | 1 | 1 |
| 110000016107-2 | 2 | 4 |
| 110000016107-2 | 3 | 3 |
| 110000016107-2 | 4 | 3 |
| 110000016107-2 | 5 | 2 |

Here is the desired result:

| keyInd | V1016 | V2010 | transition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110000016107-1 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 110000016107-1 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 110000016107-1 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 110000016107-1 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 110000016107-1 | 5 | 2 | nan |
| 110000016107-2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 110000016107-2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 110000016107-2 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 110000016107-2 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 110000016107-2 | 5 | 2 | nan |

So the code for each `keyInd` would be:

```
> for row in keyInd:
> > if nextrow['V2010'] != row['V2010']:
> > > row['transition'] += 1
> > else:
> > > row['transition'] = previousrow['V2010']
```

and the last row of each `keyInd` would be always `nan`

I tried `groupby('KeyInd')['V2010'].apply(transition)`, the `transition` function being:

```
def transition(s):
    array = s.to_numpy()
    changed = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        if array[i] != array[i + 1]:
            changed += 1
        result.append(changed)
    result.append(np.nan)
    return resuilt
```

but it takes forever because my dataframe has over 2 million rows

How can I solve this?

Comment: sorry but why does V2010 change in your output v/s your input? Not very clear with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `shift(-1)` to compare rows, then change the `tail(1)` to `np.nan`. Group by your keyInd, and then do the analysis on each grouping. This should avoid row-wise looping.

```
def transition(x):
    t = np.where(x['V2010']==x['V2010'].shift(-1), 0, 1)
    x['transition'] = np.cumsum(t)
    x['transition'] = x['transition'].astype('float')
    x['transition'].iat[-1] = np.nan
    return x

dft = df.groupby('keyInd').apply(transition)
```

Output:

```
In [105]: dft
Out[105]:
           keyInd  V1016  V2010  transition
0  110000016107-1      1      4       0.000
1  110000016107-1      2      4       0.000
2  110000016107-1      3      4       0.000
3  110000016107-1      4      4       1.000
4  110000016107-1      5      2         NaN
5  110000016107-2      1      1       1.000
6  110000016107-2      2      4       2.000
7  110000016107-2      3      3       2.000
8  110000016107-2      4      3       3.000
9  110000016107-2      5      2         NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the idea Jonathan, but the kernel is still dying. anyway it made me think I need to master numpy.

Comment: interesting. are there groupings that don't ever change? if so, maybe just filter those out first using unique count or something similar? otherwise, if you haven't tried, people like DASH although I've not tried it myself. I think that's the program...supposed to help with multiprocessing/threading.

Comment: I realized that I had some `np.nan` values in `keyInd` and that was spendind a lot of memory and making my kernel crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['110000016107-1',1,4],['110000016107-1',2,4],['110000016107-1',3,4],['110000016107-1',4,4],\
    ['110000016107-1',5,2],['110000016107-2',1,1],['110000016107-2',2,4],['110000016107-2',3,3],\
    ['110000016107-2',4,3],['110000016107-2',5,2]]



   import pandas
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['keyInd','V1016','V2010'])
    dataframe['diff'] = dataframe.sort_values(by='V1016',ascending=False).groupby(['keyInd'])['V2010'].diff()

  keyInd            V1016  V2010  diff
0  110000016107-1      1      4   0.0
1  110000016107-1      2      4   0.0
2  110000016107-1      3      4   0.0
3  110000016107-1      4      4   2.0
4  110000016107-1      5      2   NaN
5  110000016107-2      1      1  -3.0
6  110000016107-2      2      4   1.0
7  110000016107-2      3      3   0.0
8  110000016107-2      4      3   1.0
9  110000016107-2      5      2   NaN
```

With this dataframe you can create a function to enumerate the numbers of transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with shift, step by step

```
data = [['110000016107-1',1,4],['110000016107-1',2,4],['110000016107-1',3,4],['110000016107-1',4,4],\
        ['110000016107-1',5,2],['110000016107-2',1,1],['110000016107-2',2,4],['110000016107-2',3,3],\
        ['110000016107-2',4,3],['110000016107-2',5,2]]

import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['keyInd','V1016','V2010']).set_index('keyInd')

df['V2010_lead'] = df.groupby(level=['keyInd'])['V2010'].shift(-1)

df.loc[(df['V2010_lead'] != df['V2010']) & (df['V2010_lead'].notna()),'transition'] = 1
    
df.loc[(df['V2010_lead'].isna()),'transition'] = None
    
df.loc[(df['V2010_lead'] == df['V2010']) ,'transition'] = 0
    
df['transition_counter'] = df.groupby(level=['keyInd'])['transition'].cumsum()
```